# How do I run **either** the main CI jobs **or** an included configuration?

Tags: gitlab-ci

So I have this GitLab CI configuration where my main `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
include:
  - local: '/path/to/local/configuration.yml'

test:
  script:
    - echo "hello world"
# ...
# lots of more jobs here
```

What I want to achieve is that I run **either** the one job in `configuration.yml` **or** all the jobs (~30) in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Disabling the one job is easy since I can include a `workflow:` configuration in `configuration.yml` which lets me selectively enable/disable that configuration.

But what do I do in `.gitlab-ci.yml`? I tried with

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

But it seems as if GitLab reads in this configuration, also the other configuration is ignored since no pipeline is created at all if is set `$DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE`.

Do I really have to modify all my existing jobs in `.gitlab-ci.yml` one by one?

Comment: Sounds like you could porentially benefit from [Child / Parent Pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/pipeline_architectures.html#child--parent-pipelines)?

Comment: Not sure: I want to run **either** the 30 jobs in the main pipeline **or** the one job in the included pipeline. How would I do this with parent/child pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best thing for you to use is conditional includes.

Take the 30 jobs and extract them into an own yaml file, lets call it `default.gitlab-ci.yml`.

With the recent verison of GitLab you get conditional includes, and can do something like:

```yaml
include:
  - local: '/path/to/local/configuration.yml'
    rules:
      - if: '$DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE == "true"'

  - local: 'default.gitlab-ci.yml'
    rules:
      - if: '$DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE != "true"'
```

see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rules-with-include

be aware that this feature is available since 14.3 of GitLab

Comment: Also as a sidenote: i would prefer the include over the trigger. Simply because the trigger will create child pipelines and the overview will be different. Whereas the includes are on the same level and will be merged to a big yml file. You can simply also rename your existing gitlab-ci.yml and create a new one

Comment: Yep, I'll go for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Example using [Child / Parent Pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/pipeline_architectures.html#child--parent-pipelines):

```yaml
trigger_default:
  trigger:
    include: default.yml
  rules:
    - if: '$DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE != "true"'

trigger_special:
  trigger:
    include: special.yml
  rules:
    - if: '$DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE == "true"'
```

Comment: This still involves splitting up my default jobs in a separate file, same as [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69705350/520162).

Comment: but compared to the includes, you will have a decreased overview (imho) as there will be a child pipeline cotnaining the jobs. be aware of that - parent child pipelines are a nice feature, but they add some layers inbetween, which make them harder to use

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it could help, you can experiment with [GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#cicd-support-for-when-never-on-conditional-includes) (July 2023), which adds this new feature:

> ### CI/CD: Support for when: never on conditional includes
>
> [`include`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#include) is one of the most popular keywords to use when writing a full CI/CD pipeline. If you are building larger pipelines, you are probably using the `include` keyword to bring external YAML configuration into your pipeline.
>
> In this release, we are expanding the power of the keyword so you can use `when: never` when using [`rules` with `include`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-rules-with-include). Now, you can decide when external CI/CD configuration will be excluded when a specific rule is satisfied. This will help you write a standardized pipeline with better ability to dynamically modify itself based on the conditions you choose.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#include-with-rulesif) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/348146).

That `when: never` with `rules` on `include` would allow you to conditionally include an external configuration based on the evaluation of `rules`.

Now, you could modify your `include` statement with `rules` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, for example:

```yaml
include:
  - local: '/path/to/local/configuration.yml'
    rules:
      - if: '$DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE'
        when: never

test:
  script:
    - echo "hello world"
# ...
# lots of more jobs here
```

If the variable `DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE` is set, the `when: never` clause would prevent the inclusion of `configuration.yml`.

On the other hand, the jobs in your main `.gitlab-ci.yml` file would still run normally unless you have rules specified for them as well.

If you need to completely switch between running jobs in `configuration.yml` or in `.gitlab-ci.yml` based on the `DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE` variable, you might still need to add rules to all jobs in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
include:
  - local: '/path/to/local/configuration.yml'

test:
  script:
    - echo "hello world"
  rules:
    - if: '$DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE'
      when: never
    - when: always

# repeat for each job
job1:
  script: #...
  rules:
    - if: '$DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE'
      when: never
    - when: always

job2:
  script: #...
  rules:
    - if: '$DONT_RUN_DEFAULT_PIPELINE'
      when: never
    - when: always
# ...
```